# How to create a Linq to Entities subquery for less than operation

Tags: linq-to-entities

How do I write the following `sql` in `Linq to Entities`?

```
select * from LanguageApplicationResource as outside 
where LanguageId = 130 and 
      LastUpdatedOn < (select LastUpdatedOn from LanguageApplicationResource 
                       where LanguageId = 75 and 
                       ApplicationResourceId = outside.ApplicationResourceId)
```

I tried this but it bombs out with `Unable to create a constant value of type 'xxxx'` which makes sense but I can't figure out the `Linq to Entities` way.

```
var pendingList = LanguageApplicationResourceRepo.Table.Where(a => a.LanguageId == language.LanguageId &&
a.LastUpdatedOn < LanguageApplicationResourceRepo.Table.Where(b => b.LanguageId == defaultLanguage.LanguageId && 
b.ApplicationResourceId == a.ApplicationResourceId).FirstOrDefault().LastUpdatedOn).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var query = dbContext.LanguageApplicationResource
    .Where(u => LanguageId == 130 &&
                dbContext.LanguageApplicationResource
                     .Where(t => t.LanguageId == 75 &&
                                 t.ApplicationResourceId = u.ApplicationResourceId)
                     .Take(1)
                     .All(t => u.LastUpdatedOn < t.LastUpdatedOn)
          )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It blew up with `Unable to create a constant value of type 'SR.Data.Models.Domain.LanguageApplicationResource'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`